# History.js Implementation For Non HTML5 Browsers

Tags: html, history.js

I have an website I'm working on that uses Ajax it uses pushState and popstate, it works great in HTML5 browsers, but I want to get it to work in HTML4 browsers, IE& 8 and IE9.

I have tried History.js,
https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/
but cant' for the life of me figure out how to implement it. could some one give me some pointers?

Here is the code I'm using for HTML5,

```
if (history.pushState) {

    function currentPage(url){

    var index = /index/g,
        program = /program/g,
        photos = /photos/g,
        testimonials = /testimonials/g,
        about = /about/g,
        contact = /contact/g;

    if (program.test(url)){
        changeCurrentPage('#program');
        document.title = "Our Programs Kolibri Daycare";

    }else if (photos.test(url)){
        changeCurrentPage('#photos');
        document.title = "Photos Kolibri Daycare";

    }else if (testimonials.test(url)){
        changeCurrentPage('#testimonials');
        document.title = "Tesimonials Kolibri Daycare";

    }else if (about.test(url)){
        changeCurrentPage('#about');
        document.title = "About Kolibri Daycare";

    }else if (contact.test(url)){
        changeCurrentPage('#contact');
        document.title = "Contact Kolibri Daycare";
    }else {
        changeCurrentPage('#home');
        document.title = "Kolibri Daycare";
    }
}

function changeContent(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "getContents.php?url=" + url,
        success: function(responseText){  
            $("#content").html(responseText);  
        }
    });
    currentPage(url);
}

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
    if (settings.url == 'getContents.php?url=photos.html') {
        $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
            'overlayShow'   : false,
            'cyclic'        : true,
            'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut'     : 'elastic'
        });
    }
});



$(document).ready(function() {
    var elems = null,
        links = null,
        link = null,
        i;

    elems = document.getElementById('nav');
    links = elems.getElementsByTagName('a');

    if (links) {
        for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            links[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    var url = $(this).attr("href");
                    changeContent(url);
                    history.pushState(null, null, url);
                    e.preventDefault();

                }, false);
            }
        }

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            /*window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {*/
        window.onpopstate = function (e) {
            var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
            var n = pathArray.length;
            if (pathArray[n-1]){
            changeContent(pathArray[n-1]);
        }else {
            changeContent('index.html');

        }
    /*}, false);*/
    }
    }, 1);
});
}
```

Here is a link to the test site.
http://robfenwick.com/kolibri4/index.html

Comment: could you clarify what exactly is the problem? from a quick look at the github history.js project it seems very simple to implent using the snippet in the gist

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing History.js HTML4 Fallback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186466/implementing-history-js-html4-fallback)

Answer (score 0):

Ok maybe the problem was that you weren't using History.js in the right way ( that's the problem i was having too ). Basically to use History.js in the correct way you must do something like:

```
// Register navigation click handlers where you will load Ajax content
$( window ).on( 'click', 'a.ai1ec-load-view', handle_click_on_link_to_load_view );
// Bind to the statechange event
$( window ).bind( 'statechange', handle_state_change );

// When the state changes, load the corresponding view
var handle_state_change = function( e ) {
    var state = History.getState();
    load_view( state.url, 'json' );
};

// When clicking on a link you want to load, trigger statechange by changing state
var handle_click_on_link_to_load_view = function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    History.pushState( { target :this }, null, $( this ).attr( 'href' ) );
};
```

Before doing this i wasn't listening to `statechange` and i was simply using pushState() in the link click handler.

If you do it like this there is no need to code a fallback, it will work also in html4 browsers ( and bookmarks from html4 browsers will work as expected )